# How to detect the burst data?

Tags: digital-communications

At high SNR i am able to detect the burst by taking the magnitude of the data and setting the threshold. for low SNR it it difficult to set the threshold?

Comment: yes, it's difficult. So you need to take all you know about the signal into account. We don't know your signal, so we can't help you. You need to go into far, far, far more detail about your system. There's no general solution!

Comment: Many communications systems start by sending a known pattern first.  It has no information value, but does help the receiver detect that the data is there and recover some communications parameters.

Comment: Its actually a qpsk modulated signal. with snr of 10 dB to achieve BER 10-6.